# Build an android app on Windows Device

Tags: windows-phone, ionic-framework, android-applicationinfo

I have an Android app build using Ionic Framework. Now, how to deploy and test that android app on Windows phone (what tools are to be used and steps followed)..

Answer (score 0):

**1**.Get Windows 8 OS.

**2**.Download and Install Microsoft Visual Studio Update 4

**3**.Then From there, you can use the IDE to create Cordova or Ionic Project(          provided Ionic Plugins and Project have been Installed), Also you can also use the Command Line Interface to create your project, I'll advice the Command Line Interface as the best OPTIONS.

**4**.From the means, you can build your and will have the .appx (for WINDOWS STORE APP) that you can sideload to your actual device.

You need to register your windows phone to your windows phone developer account then you will be able to install it in your phone here is link, that show you how to register device.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn614128.aspx#prerequisites27

ionic is not supporting windows platform properly. i had developed application in android and ios using ionic but when i start to build those app for windows platform then so many feature of lonic-framework were not properly working. it require too many custom changes in ionic library as well.

Comment: The build for android platform was successful but the build for windows phone 8 platform was giving errors. Could you notify the reason for the error.This is error I got... I have filed it in Stackoverflow

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31849724/build-wp8-of-an-android-app-using-ionic-framework